# How to add the images folder in ckeditor in html file

Tags: html, ckeditor

how to add the 'images' folder that appears by default in CK Editor when you try and upload an image. I want the images with main-folder and sub-folder to appear in the folder tree. Im using normal Ckeditor in html file.

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    fullPage: true,
        extraPlugins: 'mention,imageuploader',
        allowedContent: true,
        autoGrow_onStartup: true,
                filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/imgbrowser.php?type=Images',
                filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/imgupload.php?type=Images'
    });
```

I have added the image uploader plugins in the plugin folder and add the above code in my html file. then i clicked on imgae icon and popup will be opened. There im able to see the "browse" button. Once i clicked the browse button, im able to see the images where i have saved in the folder.

But im facing issue that if i click upload button, images are not attaching. page got stucked after clicked upload button.
http://localhost/admin_29/ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/imgupload.php

Actually im looking that, once we clicked on the browse-server button.popup should open. In that popup,

1. List item

left side,folder should be there. If i click any image on the folder

2. List item

Right side, Image should display

3. List item

If i click upload button in the popup, new image should upload and image should save in the folder itself

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my past experience if using localhost and especially chrome, you will get errors. Check out your dev console and most likely see some kind of error like:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///F:/.../images/logo.png
```

Since you can browse the image folder might just be localhost issue. Why not try in on web server and see if works ok?